# Heroku fail to migrate due to ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When I tried to `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I was told that connection cannot be made. I'm using postgres locally. I can see my site loaded properly, but I can't access my models. How to fix this?

```
Rexs-MacBook-Pro:portfolio Rex$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on fathomless-mesa-1536... up, run.4069
 ▸    ECONNREFUSED: connect ECONNREFUSED 50.19.103.36:5000
```

Answer (score 7):

I have magically thought of why and it worked. Basically, my school's internet's firewall blocked my connection to heroku. After I have switched to my own mobile date it works like it should be!

Answer (score 4):

It's the firewall. Same thing happened to me when trying to connect from a public library. Simply use a VPN, like TunnelBear, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I had the same issue.
At first I thought this error would come from the database maybe due to a wrongly set up password in the database.yml, but it was really just a firewall issue. I was working from a public space - a café.

So I connected via my phone and I could run heroku commands like `heroku run bin/rails db:migrate`.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30480420)